# Run WSL2 inside VMware Workstation 15

Tags: hyper-v, vmware-workstation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[VMWare workstation 15.5.5 now supports Host Hyper-V mode](https://blogs.vmware.com/workstation/2020/05/vmware-workstation-now-supports-hyper-v-mode.html), which enables WSL 2 to be run.

How do I setup Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 inside a VMware guest?

Answer (score 6):

#### Before you begin

I've noticed a slow down since installing WSL2, so I'd first recommend that you take a snapshot and compare performance before / after running WSL2.  Perhaps WSL1 will better suit your needs.  VMware doesn't seem keen to publish performance metrics of virtualising Intel VT-x/EPT.

#### Install Windows Subsystem for Linux

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart
```

#### Enable Virtual Machine Platform

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart
```

#### Enable Intel VT-x/EPT

Reboots have been disabled by `/norestart` above, so power down and enable Intel VT-x:

Settings -> Hardware -> Processors -> Virtualise Intel VT-x/EPT

Note again the advice from [this page](https://www.nnguyen14.com/2018/10/understanding-vmware-hardware.html):

> [...]it will slow down your VM tremendously[...]

#### Set default WSL version 2

For new installs:

```
wsl --set-default-version 2
```

For an existing install (eg, ubuntu)

```
wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2
```

#### Troubleshooting

If you get a WSL hexadecimal error, [update the kernel](https://wslstorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/wslblob/wsl_update_x64.msi).  I got this error before enabling VT-x/EPT, so maybe you won't bump into it.

I didn't record the error that required the kernel update, so please either edit this answer or post the error message in the comments.

Comment: Note that as of Feb 2022 you cannot run WSL 2 both in a VMware guest and on the host at the same time. If WSL 2 (and thus Hyper-V) is enabled on the host, VMware uses Hyper-V as the virtualization engine, just providing the UI and things like sound and USB virtualization. However, Workstation cannot do nested virtualization (required to run WSL2 in a guest) if the host has Hyper-V enabled. In theory this could be fixed since Hyper-V itself does allow nested virtualization, and with Microsoft and VMware having partnered up hopefully it will get fixed in a future Workstation release.